# Автодополнение в zsh для одной команды?

Tags: zsh

Использую zsh. Написал скрипт `test`. Добавил его в `$PATH`, `chmod`-ул и все дела. Ему можно передавать несколько параметров, а можно название файла (без пути), который сам скрипт ищет потом в заданной директории.

Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы при нажатии `<TAB>`, `zsh` сам предлагал мне файлы находящиеся в заданной директории.

Я так понимаю это связано с `zstyle`. С английский есть проблемы.
Если кому не сложно, напишите куда смотреть, что читать или пример какой.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кратко, то в чем-то разобрался используя [это](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/blob/master/zsh-completions-howto.org).

Когда `zsh` ловит `<TAB>` он начинает искать автодополнение для данной команды (оформляемое в виде отдельного файла) в директориях, указанных в `fpath`.

Для меня все свелось в создание файла `_test` в директории `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix`, содержащий:

```
#compdef test

_arguments \
    '-c[указать имя конфигурационного файла]:filename:(`ls /home/<username>/workspace/test/conf | grep .rb`)' \
    '-d[указать директорию с конфигурационными файлами]' \
    '-h[помощь]'
```

Вот так все просто) Enjoy!